# How to extract a TTF from a font collection (TTC, DFONT) using fontKit in Node

Tags: node.js, fonts, stream, buffer, truetype

trying to programmatically extract a single TTF font from a true-type Mac font collection (TTC or DFONT) and save it (much like online sites like https://transfonter.org/ttc-unpack allow).
fonts[0] is the first font in the collection (Book) and i am trying to save it as a separate TTF font. When I run the code below, the TTF file saved is as big as the original TTC (1.6mb) and still holds the various TTFFonts (not just the Book), so obviously **.stream.buffer** is not the way to go.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const fontkit = require('fontkit');
const ttfFont = fontkit.openSync('/System/Library/Fonts/Avenir.ttc').fonts[0];


fs.writeFileSync('Avenir-Book.ttf', ttfFont.stream.buffer);
```

Any ideas how to save a single TTF from the TTC collection?

thnx