# How to extract TTC file to TTF file

Tags: node.js, truetype

I tried to extract TTC file to TTF use fontkit, but I get object font. how can I get font file?

Here is my code:

```
var collection = fontkit.openSync('C:\\Users\\Documents\\C\\Optima.ttc');
var name = collection.fonts
var f = collection.getFont(name[0].postscriptName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it reading the internal buffer (it is not documented):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const fontkit = require('fontkit')

var collection = fontkit.openSync('./a-font-collection.ttc')
collection.fonts.forEach(ttf => {
  console.log(ttf.familyName)
  fs.writeFileSync(`${ttf.familyName}.ttf`, ttf.stream.buffer)
})
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, i try it, but i got a the TTF file saved is as big as the original TTC. and can't open it. i think it write a new file same ttc file. but saved with name .ttf

Comment: because ttf.stream.buffer is the stream of ttc file

Comment: here, i got same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60911697/how-to-extract-a-ttf-from-a-font-collection-ttc-dfont-using-fontkit-in-node

Comment: It seems an [old issue](https://github.com/foliojs/fontkit/issues/156) I will check

Comment: oh yes. same it. hope you can problem solving, i really need it. thanks

Comment: Make sure to check whether the font EULA permits what you're trying to do.